# refresh power query after column added to source table?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have an excel workbook (book1) with a table of data.

In another workbook (book2) I have a power query that uses this data as a source. The idea is to easily have a local read-only copy of the table from book1 available in book2.

I can't quite figure out how to update my query when an additional column is added to the source. Nothing I have tried pulls this new column into the query. I am confused since looking at the M code it appears to simply reference the entire table in book1:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("M:\!OtherStuff\!Cellar CIP Logs\CIP Lab 2020\CIP Storage.xlsm"), null, true),
    eqm_Table = Source{[Item="eqm",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(eqm_Table,{{"Equipment", type text}, {"Category", type text}, {"Group", type text}, {"CIP Types", type text}, {"Data Type", Int64.Type}, {"Sani Duration (hrs)", type text}, {"Interval Duration (hrs)", type text}, {"Linked Status", type text}, {"Class", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Last Action", type datetime}, {"Status History", type text}, {"Last Action History", type datetime}, {"Interval Last Action", type datetime}, {"Empty", type any}, {"1 Validation", type text}, {"1 CIP Types", type text}, {"1 Value", type text}, {"2 Validation", type text}, {"2 CIP Types", type text}, {"2 Value", type text}, {"3 Validation", type text}, {"3 CIP Types", type text}, {"3 Value", type text}, {"4 Validation", type text}, {"4 CIP Types", type text}, {"4 Value", type text}, {"5 Validation", type text}, {"5 CIP Types", type text}, {"5 Value", type text}, {"6 Validation", type text}, {"6 CIP Types", type text}, {"6 Value", type text}, {"7 Validation", type text}, {"7 CIP Types", type text}, {"7 Value", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

So let's say I add a column "Empty History" after the column "Empty" in the source table. What steps are necessary to have the power query in book2 pull this new column in when it is refreshed?

Comment: I replicated this scenario and my power query workbook fetches the new column I added in the source workbook, right after I hit refresh. I don't understand why yours isn't working. Do you have any clue what it might be?

Comment: Are you relying on the query preview, or are you actually refreshing the query and loading it to a table or pivot? If preview, try clearing cache